# How do I add a Css file to my Class library?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, class-library

I have a class library which is being used by another project, it is added in the toolbox, then dragged onto the page. Works great!

Only problem is that I want some styling added.

In my class library I have:

1. added a css file "PayMyBillClassLibrary.main.css",
2. added the following to the AssemblyInfo:

   [assembly: WebResource("PayMyBillClassLibrary.main.css", "text/css")]
3. added the css file in the main class using the following code:

   ```
       string cssUrl = Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(), "PayMyBillClassLibrary.main.css");

       HtmlLink cssLink = new HtmlLink();
       cssLink.Href = cssUrl;
       cssLink.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
       cssLink.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");

       this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(cssLink);
   ```

This produces the following in the solution that I mentioned earlier which hold the class library.

```
<link href="/TestTwo/WebResource.axd?d=DkBjNt27-P0jDJmlJk7Z40MOLq_coWgDQBzgcFJIGLo-9W-RQClfELNEGAApBuu-kkPiYrB_2uU24xTCwXsn5uKPcaWSRY7vHpLnJEGzoCJ9DdIrd-9StVNbLyRKSYvvUA4x2w2&amp;t=634563635276884818" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

If I click on the link in the view source, it just shows a blank page, if I change the CSS reference to `murr.css` it will say not found. So it seems to be finding the CSS file, but not doing anything with it or picking up the CSSin the file.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: If you run fiddler, then see what is coming back from your request what do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try putting a literal control in the header, and setting the literal content in code-behind.

```
<asp:Literal id="cssliteral" runat="server" />
```

Code-behind:

```
cssLiteral.Text = String.Format("<link href='{0}' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />", cssUrl);
```

Comment: hmmm, I know I could do that, jsut seems a bit hacky

Comment: But even if you do it this way, the problem seems to be that you are not getting a valid Url at all am I right? If you inspect it with firebug or something can you see the content of that Url?

Comment: I tried all the other ones and none of them worked! So tried your and it worked!!! Thanks!